# Excel VBA copy a list of cells down, iteratively removing the first element and repeating the last

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of variables in my spreadsheet that belong to some points named "a,b,c,d..." (etc) for a varying number of points. This list is then followed by a similar list of variables (1,2,3,4..." (etc) which also varies in length.

For one column, what I'd like to do is this:

For an initial set of data, e.g. for 4 start points in rows "a","b","c","d", the first 5 cells' data would be copied from rows "a","b","c","d","d"; the next 4 would be copied from "b","c","d","d", the next 3 would be copied from "c","d","d", then "d","d".
See link (the formatting isn't necessary, I just had it in my text file to make it easier to spot the repeats). The data I would like to copy down is the column labelled "K-".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV4rK.png

I'm sure there's a way of doing this with a couple of loops, I just can't get my head around it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim str As String
str = "abcd"

str = str & Right(str, 1)
Debug.Print str

Do While Len(str) > 2
    str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1)
    Debug.Print str
Loop
```

outputs:

> abcdd bcdd cdd dd

For the same operation done on cells:

```
lRow = Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Row

Range(Cells(lRow + 1, 2), Cells(lRow * 2 - 1, 2)).Value = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lRow, 2)).Value
Cells(lRow * 2, 2).Value = Cells(lRow * 2 - 1, 2).Value

i = lRow - 1
lRow = lRow * 2
Do While i >= 2
    Range(Cells(lRow + 1, 2), Cells(lRow + i, 2)).Value = Range(Cells(lRow - i + 1, 2), Cells(lRow, 2)).Value
    lRow = lRow + i
    i = i - 1
Loop
```

Comment: I should have been more clear; in the screenshot I linked, the values of the "K-" cells are the ones I want to copy down, as opposed to just letters in the string. I just gave the point names rather than the values so that I could show the order more clearly.

Is there a similar thing I can do with reference to that particular range of cells? 

EDIT: Actually I can see I didn't mention that at all. Sorry for the lack of clarity! Have now amended question.